# React modal animation on click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, animation, modal-dialog

I have a modal, full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/8yxmz73l1j
I want to be able to animate this modal similar to the bootstrap one, with translate up and down and with fade in and out. So when I click the `delete` button it fades in the modal and when I click the button which closes the modal it fades it out. I tried to use React Transition but to no avail. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Try animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @anand I've tried but I have no idea how to implement that. Could you lend me a hand with that?

Comment: import the animate.css file into your component. Then add the relevant className to your elements. Say you want to fade in your backdrop, use `<div className="backdrop animated fadeIn" style={backdropStyle}>`

Comment: @anand Thanks, it does work! How to do that the other way? I mean how to fadeOut on close?

Comment: In your `closeModal` function, first add the className `animated fadeOut` to the backdrop, then wait for,say 200ms, and then call `this.props.closeModal();` and `setState` from inside a `setTimeout`. Actually, React Transition is meant to make this process simpler, but the documentation is not too great, I think, and I am yet to figure that out :)

Answer (score 9):

Without using javascript but simple CSS, this is possible using [keyframe animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) like this :

```
@keyframes modalFade {
  from {transform: translateY(-50%);opacity: 0;}
  to {transform: translateY(0);opacity: 1;}
}

.modal {
  animation-name: modalFade;
  animation-duration: .3s;
}
```

In your `/components/Modal/index.css` so here, you only have the animation at the modal display ! To animate the closing action, you'd want to set animation-direction to reverse then unmount the component.

Comment: Where do I implement the reverse?